# EntityFramework and handling duplicate primary key/concurrency/race conditions situations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, race-condition

I wrote a library, referenced by numerous applications, that tracks who is online and which application and page they are viewing.

The data is stored, using EF6, in a Sql Server 2008 table which tracks their username (primary key), application, page and timestamp. I only want to store the latest request for each person so each username should only be stored once.

The library code, which is called from the Global.asax of each application looks like this:

```
public static void Add(ApplicationType application, string username, string pageRequested)
{
    using (var db = new CommonDAL()) // EF context
    {
        var exists = db.ActiveUsers.Find(username);

        if (exists != null)
            db.ActiveUsers.Remove(exists);

         var activeUser = new ActiveUser() { ApplicationID = application.Value(), Username = username, PageRequested = pageRequested, TimeRequested = DateTime.Now };
         db.ActiveUsers.Add(activeUser);

         db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I'm intermittently getting the error `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tblActiveUser_Username'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblActiveUser'. The duplicate key value is (xxxxxxxx)`

What I can only guess is happening is Request A comes in, removes the existing username. Request B (from same user) then comes in, tries to remove the username, sees nothing exists. Request A then adds the username. Request B then tries to add the username. The error frequently seems to be triggered when a web server sends a client a 401 status, which again points to multiple requests within a short period of time triggering this.

I'm having trouble mocking this race condition using unit tests as I haven't done much async programming before, but tried to create async tests with delays to mock multiple simultaneous slow requests. I've tried to use `using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())` and `using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))` to lock the requests so request A can complete before request B begins but can't verify either one fixes the issue as I can't mock the situation reliably.

1) Which is the right way to prevent the exception (Most recent request is the one that ultimately is stored)?

2) Which is the right way to to write a unit test to prove this is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want to store the latest item, you could use a last update wins and avoid the race condition on who can insert first, the database handles the locks and the last to call update (which is the most recent) is what is in the table.

Something like the following should handle any primary key errors if you run into concurrency issues on the edge case that a brand new user has 2 requests at the same time and avoid an "infinite" loop of errors (well until a stack overflow exception any way).

```
public static void Add(ApplicationType application, 
                       string username, 
                       string pageRequested, 
                       int recursionCount = 0)
{
    using (var db = new CommonDAL()) // EF context
    {
        var exists = db.ActiveUsers.Find(username);

        if (exists != null)
        {
            exists.propa = "someVal";
        }
        else
        {

            var activeUser = new ActiveUser 
            { 
                ApplicationID = application.Value(), 
                Username = username, 
                PageRequested = pageRequested, 
                TimeRequested = DateTime.Now 
            };

            db.ActiveUsers.Add(activeUser);
        }
        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch(<Primary Key Violation>)
        {
            if(recursionCount < x)
            {
                Add(application, username, pageRequested, recursionCount++)
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As for unit testing this, it will be very hard unless you insert an artificial delay or can force both threads to run at the same time.  Sometimes the timing on the race conditions is in the millisecond range depending on the issue.  Tasks may not work because they are not guaranteed to run at the same time, you throw them to the background thread pool and they run when they can.  Old school threads may work but I don't know how to force it since the time between read and remove & create are most likely in the 5 ms range or less.